# Как сделать звук смерти после смерти объекта?

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity3d-android, unity3d-editor, unity3d-faq

У меня есть объект `Ship` с событием `Died` и методом `Die`. Есть объект `ShipAudio`, который отлавливает различные события у `Ship` и проигрывает соответствующие звуки через `AudioSource`.
Метод `Die` просто деактивирует объект и инвоукает событие.

`ShipAudio`, отловив `Died`, должен проигрывать звук взрыва. Но он этого не делает, из-за того, что `ShipAudio` прикреплён к тому же объекту, что и `Ship`, поэтому `SetActive` скрывает их обоих.

Кто бы что сделал с этой ситуацией? Можно `ShipAudio` расположить на другом объекте, но что если громкость звука в игре меняется в зависимости от удалённости `Ship`? Тогда удобнее, чтобы `Ship` и `ShipAudio` находились на одном объекте.

Код:

```
public class Ship : MonoBehavior
{
    public UnityEvent Died;

    public void Die()
    {
        gameObject.SetActive(false);
        Died?.Invoke();
    }
}

public class ShipAudio : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private Ship _ship;
    [SerializeField] private AudioClip _explosionAudio;

    private AudioSource _source;

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        _ship.Died.AddListener(OnDied);
    }

    private void OnDisable()
    {
        _ship.Died.RemoveListener(OnDied);
    }

    private void OnDied()
    {
        _source.clip = _explosionAudio;
        _source.Play();
    }
}
```

Comment: Вижу как минимум 2 варианта: перенести отписку от события из `OnDisable` в `OnDied` или `OnDestroy`. Либо инвокать событие `Died` перед `SetActive`. Напишите, если ни один из вариантов не сработает, предложу еще.

Comment: @KOTlK, к сожалению, нет. SetActive не дал ShipAudio запустить звук. Точнее OnDied сработал (Я поставил Debug.Log чтоб проверить), но звук видимо не успевает включиться, либо в самом начале прерывается

Comment: Отключать рендерер объекта вместо `SetActive` не вариант? Без сущности, которая будет контролировать звук, это все костыли.

Comment: @KOTlK, мне кажется нет, так как у объекта мог быть апдейт который бы выполнялся каждый кадр, но вы меня натолкнули на интересную идею. можно просто поотключать скрипты и рендерер. сейчас попробую. спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если ShipAudio расположен на том же объекте, который выключает в момент наступления OnDie() - то проигрывание аудио будет сразу остановлено. Как вариант

Выключать объект после окончания проигрывания.
Выключать в этом случае можно либо в методе (ниже в примере это будет корутина), вызывающем _source.Play(),

```
//public class Ship 
public void Die()
{
    Died?.Invoke();
}
//class ShipAudio
private void OnDied()
{
    StartCoroutine(PlaySoundAndDoAction());
}
private IEnumerator PlaySoundAndDoAction()
{
    _source.clip = _explosionAudio;
    _source.Play();
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(_explosionAudio.lenght);
        gameObject.SetActive(false);
}
```

либо передавать Action в Action, и уже из класса Ship решать, что делать дальше, например так:

```
//public class Ship 
Action<Action> Died;
public void Die()
{
    Died?.Invoke(()=> OnDieSoundComplete());
}
private void OnDieSoundComplete()
{
    gameObject.SetActive(false);
}

//class ShipAudio
private void OnDied(Action onComplete = null)
{
    StartCoroutine(PlaySoundAndDoAction(onComplete));
}
private IEnumerator PlaySoundAndDoAction(Action onComplete = null)
{
    _source.clip = _explosionAudio;
    _source.Play();
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(_explosionAudio.lenght);
    if(onComplete !=null)
        onComplete?.Invoke();
}
```

Еще, как вариант - можно скомбинировать костыль:
ShipAudio повесить на объект пустышку, который будет дочерним Ship.
Когда Ship погибает - то объекту с ShipAudio менять родителя на null.
После проигрывания аудио - либо уничтожать объект пустышку, либо возращать его как дочерний объекту с Ship, если планируется его повторное использование (судя потому, что он в момент смерти SetActive(false), а не Destroy()).